# Length of char array (where "int" values are stored)

Tags: c, pointers

I need to store the some integer values in the char array with same size of memory .
like `int32` should fit in `char[4]` .
so below is the thing I tried

```
int val = 123457;
char *data = val;
```

this stores properly, but If I allocate like this , I can not get the length or free it.

so I tried like this.

```
char *data = malloc(sizeof(val);
```

but How do I copy that int value .

Due to some requirement I have to store in the `char array` and get back int value from the `char array`.

Comment: You put `123457` into a `char` and say it is stored properly? Are you sure?

Comment: yes , I did this   printf(" %d \n",(int)data); it prints the correct value

Comment: int val = 123457; char *data = val;  this sets the memory address of data to 123457(good candidate for a segmentation fault error) it doesn't change the value of data.

Comment: You'll either have to use `memcpy()`, or do it manually.

Comment: @user3607698 Don't do that. You have not stored/converted the int to a text representation of the number of the int. You have just transformed an int into a char pointer (i.e. an address), that's not the purpose of pointers. Pointers should point to something valid, it should not store an int even if you don't get a compiler error when doing so. There's no point in doing what you've done, you could just as well do printf("%d\n", val); and not bother with the char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can do this is by using union(one more useless thing of c++ if you ask me).

```
union utyp {
    int i;
    char ch[sizeof(int)];
};
union utyp x;
x.i=324255;
```

Union is making all of its variables share the same memory space

324255 is 100 11110010 10011111 to binary

so for example the `(int)x.ch[2]` is 4

Comment: Heh. I'm not sure this directly solves his problem, but this is a nice technique, and much safer than other alternatives.

Comment: Why assume 4 in `char ch[4]` rather than `sizeof int`?

Comment: @chux, sizeof(int) sounds safer ,but nowdays 32 bit is almost a standard for int's.

Comment: @SteveL _Billions_ of embedded processors are made each year in 2014.  A very significant chunk, maybe most, of these are 16-bit `int`.  Further, many a high end machine is 64-bit and could use 64-bit `int`.  Thus I do not agree with "nowdays 32 bit is almost a standard for int".  In C, `int` is specified as at _least_ 16-bits.  If one wants at least 32 bits, use `long` or maybe `int32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this, but it's not wise to mingle your data types like this unless you actually know what you're doing.

This is fraught with peril, as they say.

Still, if you wish to do it, and then copy the data, you can do it like this:

```
int val = 123457;
char *data = malloc(sizeof(val);
memcpy(data, &val, sizeof(val));
```

Comment: Though, the use of malloc might be superfluous, a `char data[sizeof val];` would do

Comment: Very true. I was just copying his original code and extending it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for it , now how would I convert back to int val. I mean I need to store this back in val = (int)data;

Comment: memcpy back the other way should do it: memcpy(&val, data, sizeof(val)). Although this is even more unsafe, as it assumes that the length of data is at least the sizeof(val)

Comment: +1 This solution properly does not rely on `int` being 32-bits, nor `char` being 8-bits.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` will solve your problem. You do something like this:

```
int val = 123457;
char data[sizeof int];
memcpy(data, &val, sizeof int);
```

Just look up man page for `memcpy` for more details. Basically it copies specified number of bytes from memory pointed to by second argument to that of first argument.

**Note about endian-ness:** If your machine is little-endian then `data` above will contain the bytes in reverse byte-order of what your would see if you represented the value `123457` in binary or hex. If you want to see bytes in `data` in big-endian then you may want use following code:

```
int val = htonl(123457);
char data[sizeof int];
memcpy(data, &val, sizeof int);
```

Here `htonl` converts whatever byte-order your machine is, into network order, i.e. big-endian.

Comment: +1 This solution also properly does not rely on `int` being 32-bits, nor `char` being 8-bits and does consider endian issues.

Comment: @chux thanks for pointing out. I can understand it not relying on char being 8 bits but why int?

Comment: C's longevity is due in part to its ability to adapt to innovative platforms.  Thus `char` as 8 bits is common, but could be more (some graphics chips?).  Same for `int`.  `int` as 64-bit or 16-bit occurs in 2014.  See comment with the accepted answer.

Comment: True but surely sizeof should take care of varying sizes if int.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
int val = 123457;
char *data = val;
```

you probably meant

```
int val = 123457;
char *data = (char*)&val; // note the & to give the address of val
```

now data is pointing to the int, `data` is not holding the value, just pointing to it.

but if you want to copy the int value to the allocated memory:

```
char *data = malloc(sizeof(int));
int val = 123457;
memcpy( data, &val, sizeof(int));
```

now the int value is both stored in `data` and in `val`

you can also use a union

```
typedef union
{
    int myint;
    char mychars[sizeof(int)];

} u;
```

...

```
u myunion;
myunion.myint = 123456;
```

now you have the value 123456 in the int and you can get the characters by copying from `myunion.mychars`

Comment: +1 best answer.  Minor: 123456 _may_ not fit in an `int`.  (Embedded machines often use 16-bit `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using type casts e.g.

```
char data[8];
uint32_t a,b;  // ATTENTION! int can be 64 bit depending on architecture and compiler !
a=12345;
b=678910;
*(uint32_t *)data=a;
*(uint32_t *)(data+4)=b;
// to retrieve the values
uint32_t c=*(uint32_t *)(data+4);  // we'll get b
```

Comment: On the right track that `int` by be 64-bit (or 32-bit, 16-bit, etc.).  To be highly portable, consider that `char` could also be 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, etc.  Further there is an alignment issue with this solution.  `data` could be on an address alignment that is incompatible with `uint32_t` causing `*(uint32_t *)data=a;` to fail.

Answer (score -1):

In C `Char` having the size of `1 word or byte` means you can only store one character either a number..!!! While you trying to store a `int32` number it is having `6 chars` in terms of character. What are you saying it can't be possible with `char` in C.

Comment: What!? `int32` is 6 `char`s?

Comment: He meant `123457` has 6 characters and its an int.

Comment: Initially you defined a char array like `char[4]`, and `val = 123457` means if you try to store this `int32` in your array via `sprintf` than it can store only 5 digits.